# Can I call a JQuery Function in PHP condition?

Tags: php, jquery

something like that, I want the function "createDiv" to execute itself when a certain condition is meet.

```
    if (isset($_GET["add"]))
    {
       ?>
       <script>
           createDiv();
       </script>
       <?php
    }
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createDiv()
    {
        alert ("popup!!!");
    }
    </script>
```

How can I call the function using a if else condition instead of click?

Comment: PHP code will only execute on server side. So any changes on browser will not effect the code. You sure you want that?

Comment: Also, that's just plain **Javascript**! No jQuery in sight here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost right and should do it. But you have to include the script with the function before you attempt to call it. Or you will be trying to execute something that does not exist yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function createDiv()
{
    alert ("popup!!!");
}
</script>

if (isset($_GET["add"]))
{
   ?>

<script>
createDiv(); // will execute when it loads this line
</script>

<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if (isset($_GET["add"]))
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       createDiv();
       function createDiv()
       {
          alert ("popup!!!");
       }
     </script>
   <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function createDiv()
    {
    alert ("popup!!!");
    }
    var q="<?php echo (isset($_GET['add']))?$_GET['add']:'';?>";
    if(q!=''){
     createDiv();
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: That will cause syntax errors.

Comment: try it first :) it works

Comment: Now that you *fixed it*, yeah.